# How does 'printk' get the current time with high resolution?

Tags: linux, printk

Each time `printk` outputs something, a high-resolution time will automatically be showed in a square bracket at the beginning of the line. How does `printk` get the current time with high resolution? I also wanted to get such a high resolution time in my kernel module code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`getnstimeofday()`](https://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/kernel-api/re28.html).